# summarising totals with different date ranges

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I've got a table like

| ymd | cus_id | order | order_value | refunds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 12020 | 3 | 134 | 1 |
| 2023-06-04 | 27383 | 1 | 80 | 0 |
| 2023-07-13 | 23823 | 2 | 111 | 2 |
| 2023-04-22 | 12020 | 7 | 323 | 3 |

but a lot larger, with records of each cus_id and their orders,order_value, refunds per day.

I'm needing to summarise this table, with a line for each cus_id and the sum of orders,order_value, refunds with different date ranges (full dataset, last 4 weeks, 8 weeks and 12 weeks). The end result would be similar to below so would get the 4 date ranges for each cus_id.

| date_range | cus_id | sum_order | sum_order_value | sum_refunds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all | 12020 | 23 | 1340 | 9 |
| 4 weeks | 12020 | 3 | 152 | 1 |
| 8 weeks | 12020 | 8 | 423 | 2 |
| 12 weeks | 12020 | 20 | 1023 | 7 |

n.b values in the tables are made up so might not match between the two datasets

What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking of calculating each date range separately and adding a new `date_range` column then a union with all 4 of the date ranges so end result would be like this but not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be create at "date_range" CTE (Common Table Expressions) defining each of those ranges and then join your table to that CTE.

The CTE would just be a union of the 4 different select statements giving you a row for each of your date ranges with a start and end date.  I added a sort_order column to assist with sorting the final results.

Here is a working example, this will not match your output above since that dataset wad not provided.  I used the sample data you provided and added a couple of my own:

```
with date_range as (
    select 'all' as date_range,
        cast('1900-01-01' as date) as start_date,
        current_date as end_date,
        1 as sort_order
    union
    select '4 weeks' as date_range,
        cast((current_date - interval '28' day) as date) as start_date,
        current_date as end_date,
        2 as sort_order
    union
    select '8 weeks' as date_range,
        cast((current_date - interval '56' day) as date) as start_date,
        current_date as end_date,
        3 as sort_order
    union
    select '12 weeks' as date_range,
        cast((current_date - interval '84' day) as date) as start_date,
        current_date as end_date,
        4 as sort_order
),
sample_data as(
    select *
    From (
            values(cast('2023-01-01' as date), 12020, 3, 134, 1),
                (cast('2023-06-04' as date), 27383, 1, 80, 0),
                (cast('2023-07-13' as date), 23823, 2, 111, 2),
                (cast('2023-04-22' as date), 12020, 7, 323, 3),
                (cast('2023-07-22' as date), 12020, 7, 400, 4),
                (cast('2023-08-20' as date), 27383, 9, 100, 0)
        ) as test_date(ymd, cus_id, "order", order_value, refunds)
)
select date_range,
    cus_id,
    sum("order") as sum_order,
    sum(order_value) as sum_order_value,
    sum(refunds) as sum_refunds,
    sort_order
from date_range dt
    join sample_data td on td.ymd between dt.start_date and dt.end_date --here is where you would add your own table removing the sample_data cte above
group by date_range,
    cus_id,
    sort_order
order by cus_id,
    sort_order
```

Give the results of:
[image]